# Configuring Ubuntu to use 2 graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ati, graphics, radeon

I have a desktop that as 2 graphics card that connect 5 monitors. They are a Radeon HD 7970 and a Radeon HD 8490. Ubuntu detects both of them however only the monitors connected to the 7970 are working. I can see the 8490 in CCC but I can't do anything with it. I am using the latest driver from Ubuntu's proprietary driver install. Any help would be appreciated.

My xorg.conf is

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Default Card 0"
    Driver "fglrx"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Default Card 1"
    Driver "fglrx"
    BusID "PCI:2@0:0:0"
EndSection
```

and lspci shows this

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti XT [Radeon HD 7970/8970 OEM / R9 280X]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti XT HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7970 Series]
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos XTX [Radeon HD 8490 / R5 235X OEM]
02:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6400 Series]
```

Comment: I can't swear this is the problem you are having but I recently had a problem where in order to make my installation work with a different but similar graphics card, I had to UNINSTALL the proprietary driver.  Would I be correct in assuming the card with the proprietary driver, the 8490, is the one you had first, and when you added the second card you ran into trouble?

Let me know and I'll tell you how to uninstall those drivers.  It wasn't obvious, though not at all difficult once I figured out how.

Comment: I had the 7970 installed first and then the 8490 second but this is a fresh install. When using the open source driver it detects 4 monitors but it's very buggy. The screen flickers, I can't move the display, the two connected via DP MST are mirrored.

Comment: I have the same problem, and they have never worked...